# Wordpress Filter Categories

Tags: wordpress

How do get all the sub categories id ?
Catrgories and subcatrgories are like

```
2013
   April 10
   April  9
   April  8 
   March  10
   March  9
2012
  June 10
  May 6
      May 5
Cast
Group
Party
```

How do I get all the subcategory id's of the month?
I need this to pagination to show page links like site.com/catrgory/catrgory-slug/issue/{year}/{month}/{day}. I need to show pagination with links to subcategory pages.
Which list all the post of the particular subcategory.

I am using the rewrite url

```
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'past_issue_rewrite_rules');
function past_issue_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) {

    // handles paged/pagination requests
    $new_rules = array('category/catrgory-slug/issue/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/' => '?year='.$wp_rewrite->preg_index(1).'&month='.$wp_rewrite->preg_index(2).'&day='.$wp_rewrite->preg_index(3));

    // Add the new rewrite rule into the top of the global rules array
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tired this and it is working

```
$root_categories = get_categories( array('parent' => 0,'hide_empty ' => 1, 'order' => 'desc'));
$categories = array();
if(empty($root_categories)){ return $categories;}
foreach($root_categories as $category){ 
    if(preg_match('/\d{4}$/',$category->name, $matches)) {
        $subcategories = get_categories('child_of='.$category->cat_ID.'&hide_empty=1&order=desc');
        if(!empty($subcategories)) {
            foreach($subcategories as $subcatgory) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```